# Ubuntu 11.04 hangs many times in a day

Tags: 11.04, unity, firefox, rhythmbox

I upgraded from 10.10 to 11.04,My pc hangs many times.

What does hung mean here?
My mouse pointer is stuck and I can't use shortcut keys,and I can't run Alt+F2 and incase I hear music,last song sequence is being repeated again and again.

When does MY pc hung?
1.While hearing to songs in Rhythm Box.
2.While using Firefox 4.

I am using Unity,how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using proprietary drivers? What's you graphic drivers? Maybe it's a problem with your graphic board or software installation. Are you using 64bits version or other?

Comment: I don't use any graphics card,I have shared 512 MB card and I use 32 bit.

Comment: Yes, but you've installed the proprietary drivers?... When i had ubuntu 10.10 i've had some of the issues you complaint about and my computer just freezes. So, i discovered that one of the problems was that i didn't have installed the proprietary drivers. Just go to Drivers and install it. Let's give it a try.

Comment: To be frank no ,might be I forgot,can you tel how to check those ?

Comment: just click super key (windows key) and then write down "Drivers"... then a window will open. That window would say if there are any graphic drivers installed. Check if it is proprietary drivers... if not, just installed it.

Comment: Maybe you could check this previous question:

[Does Unity needs proprietary graphics?][1]



  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/q/21427/15945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Ubuntu Classic is my recommendation for the moment. When you are in the Login Window look in the lower right part of the screen. There is an option there that you can change to select what Ubuntu interface you want to login to. The options are:

Ubuntu (Which is the one that has Unity)
Ubuntu Classic
Ubuntu Classic (No Effecs) <-- This is the one i use to solve many weird problems.

Comment: Presently I have switched to Ubuntu Classic(No effects),let see the working.